# Unsubscribe Lambda Event Handler **With Closure**

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

I know a lot of people have asked the question of "how do I unsubscribe the following"

```
myButton.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
```

With the obvious answer of

```
EventHandler HelloWorld = delegate { MessageBox.Show("Hello World!"); };
myButton.Click -= HelloWorld;
myButton.Click += HelloWorld;
```

But what I'm using a lambda to create a closure?  What if my object has an event called `AssessmentRationChanged` that is of type `Action`, and I'm wiring it thusly:

```
foreach (MassFMVUpdateDTO dto in CurrentProperties)
   dto.AssessmentRationChanged += () => setCellColorBasedOnAssessmentRatioValue(dto);
```

What if there's a chance I've already set this handler for some / all of the objects in this loop?  Is there a way to unsubscribe them?

I'm sure I could use reflection and clear the handler completely, but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you have to store the references to the delegates, basically.

Remember everything that you'll want to unsubscribe later.

Comment: Grrrr.  So probably re-work my design and pass a sender along in the event? - `Action<MassFMVUpdateDTO>` -  Thanks as always Jon.

Comment: @Adam: You haven't made the rest of the context clear enough for us to say whether or not you'd want to change the design. I'm not sure how passing a sender would help though...

Comment: Sorry for misspelling your name :)  Wouldn't adding a sender allow me to just wire the event up directly to the method, so that I could unsubscribe it later?  ie  `dto.AssessmentRationChanged += setCellColorBasedOnAssessmentRatioValue;` instead of what I have now with the closure

Comment: @Adam: Oh, I see. Yes, quite possibly. So change it to an `Action<MassFMVUpdateDTO>`? Yes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the lambda to create a delegate instance that you can use later to unsubscribe:

```
 Action a = () => setCellColorBasedOnAssessmentRatioValue(dto);

 myObject.MyEvent += a;

 // to unsubscribe:
 myObject.MyEvent -= a;
```

Comment: That's a sharp idea, the problem is that this is in a loop, and there are many such dto's, so I'd have to keep track of which Action goes with which DTO, which, while doable, is a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote this:

> I'm sure I could use reflection and clear the handler completely

The obvious answer would be to use a simple delegate instead of an event:

```
foreach (MassFMVUpdateDTO dto in CurrentProperties)
   dto.AssessmentRationChanged = () => setCellColorBasedOnAssessmentRatioValue(dto);
```